# handle two way of 1080p, 60fps camera feed to WIFI network in low latency?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, streaming

In my robotics, I need to stream 2 way of 1080p, 60fps camera feed in H.264 to the local WIFI network ( for example a mobile phone receives the camera feed), the requirement for the latency between robotics and mobile receiver is 20ms - 30ms.

In 1080p/60fps, Megapixels: 2.1 MP (2,073,600 pixels) and BluRay H.264 : 16.8 MB/s = 134 Mbps. So with two camera feeds in both 1080p, 60fps are at least 258 Mbps.

I wonder could RasberryPI's capability could handle this work ?

Answer (score 2):

Really, really, really unlikely.  For starters, you are talking about two cameras, which presumably are going to be attached to the USB ports, and then a wifi adapter as well on the same bus (since the Pi 3's built in is 150 Mbps); in theory it should allow for this, but in reality I've never seen anyone claim that it gets much beyond 50 MB/s all told, and that's doing one thing via a USB cable.

The best chance you might have is using a Pi 3 with a second USB wifi adapter (on a different wifi channel or frequency, which may make things awkward), and a Pi camera on the CSI port, then a USB cam, to share the load around.  At best I'd call that an interesting demo/experiment and not something that should be recommended to people who are shopping around with a specific goal in mind.

I believe there are add on boards that will allow you to run two pi cameras on the CSI port but I do not know how well they actually perform; again you are looking at very bleeding edge as opposed to proven technology.

Answer (score 1):

The RPi3 has built-in WiFi, but I wouldn't expect it to have much range with only a circuitry antenna.
You could always use a WiFi USB dongle on the RPi2, one with a large physical antenna, but again, my experience with the RPi is that network speeds aren't what you would expect them to be.

Comment: I think I would use a WIFI USB dougle, how about the PI 's processing power, would it be able to process (compress and send) 134 Mbps data within 20 ms ?

Comment: @user824624 unlikely I don't see anything like that kind of frame rate when streaming

Comment: @SteveRobillard  I just found Snapdragon Flight developer boards supports 1080p/60 with parallel FPV, so that streaming is possible with that rate

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to reduce the quality constraints, you can do it. You would probably need Pi 3 or better and the latest version of Raspbian.

I was able to do it with two USB cameras using the Motion-Project/Motion library, easily installed using 'sudo apt-get install motion'

Their GitHub project:
https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion
(their docs explain how to setup for two cameras)

This tutorial was particularly useful in getting started.
http://sjj.azurewebsites.net/?p=701

To be clear, this works with one (or more) USB cameras and the Pi camera, (although I have not tested with the Pi Camera myself)

I also haven't tried yet pushing the resolution to 1080p. (My cheap webcams only do 640x480), so I'm not sure what that will do to latency/frame rate, but it's all very configurable, so if a tradeoff is an option, then this could be a solution.